# Angular directive selector do not work on element inside external library

Tags: angular, directive

In my module I've declared an Angular directive with the selector:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'input'
})
```

I though it would be applied also on input elements in templates of components declared in external modules that I import in the same module my directive is declared.

So in my app I've something like this:

```
<my-library-component [(ngModel)]="myModel"></my-library-component>
```

The template of my-library-component renders an input.
In my module i'm importing the module where my-library-component is declared and exported.

Is it the expected behavior?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to use your directive, you have to import it first (imports or delcares). The same would have to be done in external module.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed expected behaviour, as inside an external Module, you can only use Components, that are declared inside this Module (or Components, which come with a Module, which the external Module imports)

Comment: even if I'm importing an external module that declares and exports all of its component ? (including my-library-component)

Comment: My understandig is, that you want to use your directive from inside the `my-library-component`. If that is true, than the Module where `my-library-component` is declared needs to either declare the directive itself, or needs to import the directive from another module

Comment: I thought I could declare a directive with a wide-scope selector like 'input', and I expected this directive would be applied to all inputs, including the inputs found in template of components (like my-library-component) of external modules.

Comment: This is not the case, Components/Directives/Pipes are only visible inside the declaring Module (and, if they are exported, also inside the Modules which Import their Module)

Comment: Well in my module I've declared a directive, and I'm importing an external module that exports the component my-library-component... So I'm still thinking the directive should be applied also to my-library-component, since it is imported in the same module the directive id declared:D

Comment: The directive will be applied, but only inside the Template-Code which you have written inside your Module. Not inside the external Component.

Comment: Yep, sadly :) is there some official reference about this behavior? thank you Karsten

Comment: Well, not exactly on this specific situation, but you can get it from here https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules
and from here
https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-api